# Handle windows-1252 and unicode in java

Tags: java, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding, arrays

After a http request, I have got a byte array encoded with utf-8, e.g.:

```
byte[] array = new byte[]{0xc3, 0xa4, 0xc2, 0x96}
```

I decode the byte array using
`new String(array, "UTF-8")`.

In the example the first decoded char is `0xe4` which represents the letter `ä` in Unicode – so far no problem. The second char `0x96` stands for the en dash `–` in Windows-1252 while it represents some control character called `spa start of guarded area` in Unicode.

As Java is interpreting the char as Unicode I get some invisible character.

**My Question:** How can I correctly decode the byte array to get `ä–` (`0xe4 0x2013` in Unicode).

Thanks in advance for you help :)

Comment: There is no such thing as a "Unicode string" or a "Latin-1" string; a string is simply a sequence of characters.

Comment: You *explicitly* specified UTF-8. What did you expect?

Comment: Why don't you decode using `new String(array, "Latin-1")` ?

Comment: "_No Idea who did this nonsense_" Look in a mirror and you'll see him/her. Look at your code. Do you think `"UTF-8"` secretly means `"Latin-1"` or that the compiler/runtime can magically tell that you wanted something other than what you told it?

Comment: "while it is in fact a Latin-1 string" - you just said it was encoded with UTF-8. It's very unclear what you're talking about...

Comment: If you need to have some way to detect encoding, take a look at [universalchardet](https://code.google.com/p/juniversalchardet/) project. If server encoding is known and will not change in time, just use "latin-1" for I/O and string/batearray conversions in your code, as mentioned authors before me.

Comment: My question may have been unclear.

Comment: You can edit it to add information or clarify issues.

Comment: Sure, a String is just a sequence of characters. But characters are represented by numbers. And which number stands for which character depends on the table you use (e.g. Unicode or Latin-1).
Java always uses the Unicode table, but the guy who wrote the server apparently used the Latin-1 table. He then encoded the (Latin-1-) characters with UTF-8 – which for me does not make sense.
Sure I've tied decoding the byte array directly with Latin-1, but all I get is `Ã¤Â ` - which are the four chars (the fours is invisible) the four bytes in my example represent in latin-1.

Comment: @fge Please excuse my inaccurateness. I was talking about characters which can be represented using different character-tables.

Comment: @Dach Please edit your Question with clarifications and details rather than posting comments (as long as essence of Question remains the same).

Comment: @olexd Thanks for your answer. The problem is, that the server does not provide any encoding information in the html tree. That's why I have to handle the encoding myself. Although the universalchardet project looks very promising, it may not solve my problem, as Firefox, which apparently uses this library, also fails to encode the Sequence correctly.

Comment: I don’t know what Latin table you are using, but *all Latin-1 character’s numbers are identical to Unicode’s code-points*. It seems that you are confusing the standardized character encodings with some proprietary Microsoft code pages.

Comment: @Holger You are totally correct. As a Windows user I confused the Latin-1 Table for Windows-1252. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your server confuses the ISO-Latin-1 encoding with the proprietary Windows-1252 code page and the encoded data are the result of this. The Windows-1252 code page differs only at a few places from ISO-Latin-1.

You can fix the data by converting them back to the bytes the server has seen using the wrongly assumed Latin-1 and interpret them as CP1252 afterwards, as follows:

```
String string = new String(array, "UTF-8");
byte[] fix = string.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1);
string = new String(fix, "Windows-1252");
```

Comment: Thank you very much.
That's exactly what causes the problem. Thanks to your solution I can now compensate it.

Comment: If the bytes are encoded as UTF-8 then they are NOT encoded as ISO8859-1 or Windows-1252. And vice versa. Decoding the original bytes using the wrong charset produces the wrong characters, and then re-encoding the (now corrupt) characters just so you can decode them again (corrupting further) is useless. Just decode the original bytes using the correct charset to begin with.

Comment: You SHOULD be following the HTTP spec and look at the response's `Content-Type` header to know which charset the response is actually using.  If there is no charset defined, use an appropriate default as defined by the HTTP protocol or the particular media type.

Comment: `ä–` in UTF-8 is `0xc3 0xa4 0xe2 0x80 0x93`, so `0xc3 0xa4 0xc2 0x96` is clearly not UTF-8 and should not be decoded it as UTF-8.  The only way that `ä–` could end up as `0xc3 0xa4 0xc2 0x96` is if the server is incorrectly encoding data.  You need to fix the server to encode data correctly, not make the client hack a fix around it.  If you get corrupted data in, you are going to get corrupted data out.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau: I already wrote that it is the server which is wrong. It obviously reads in a cp1252 encoded file but treats it as latin1 encoded when converting it to UTF8. Surely, fixing the server should be the preferred option, but we don’t know whether that option is available.